# C++ deleteting object in constructor?

Tags: c++, string, object, constructor, nlp-question-answering

i want to make class which has one string atributte. But if string has length more then 50 characters i dont want create object. What should i do?

````
{
    if (paSlovo.length() <= DLZKA_SLOVA)
        aSlovo = paSlovo;
    else
        delete this;
    
} ```
````

Comment: The only way to abort a constructor is to throw an exception from it.

Comment: Is this really a property of a class or rather property of your use scenario in which case you should do the check **before** you even attempt to create an object. As for constructor, you can always throw an exception.

Comment: `delete this` in a constructor will cause any usage of the object (who's construction has been ended) to have undefined behaviour.   Throw an exception instead - the net effect for the caller is that the object has never existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing this trough the constructor you can do this with a function that will either provide you with the object if the criteria is met or you get a nullptr.

Make sure to correctly delete the object when done or make use of smart ptrs

```
//create object
bar* TryCreateMyObj(string const& paSlovo) const
{
    //only create object if string is less than 50
    if (paSlovo.length() <= DLZKA_SLOVA)
    {
        return new bar();
    }
    return nullptr
}
```

Comment: Better change that function to hand out a `std::unique_ptr<bar>`. `std::optonal<bar>` is another good option for a return type.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ would either of you recommend to make this function a class level function of the returning type (i.e. `static bar::`) or a method of the requesting object, or a global non-method function alltogether?

Comment: @Vroomfondel _shrug_

Comment: @Vroomfondel depends on your usage/structure realy. If you want, you can make this a static function in the class and hide/ = delete  the default constructor. This way you gaurentee other users make use of that function.